# Server Error in '/' Application (only in Firefox)

Tags: asp.net, firefox, iis

I have a bit of a brain teaser. I am getting the attached server error when I load ANY page on my website[image: Server Error]. However, this ONLY happens in Firefox. Any other browser loads the page just fine. I have cleared my cache and have completely uninstalled and re-installed FireFox to no avail. Any idea why a server error would only show up in certain browsers? This is a windows based machine running IIS. I'm totally stumped. Thanks!

Comment: Request Headers are the most likely cause as they can differ between browsers. Follow the advice in the message and generate the exception from a debug build to isolate the location.

Comment: try to run application on your peers machine or another machine? Try to remove, temp files using %temp%, and restart IIS

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see the exception type because the text is so small on you resized image.

Have you tried monitoring the request using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), or launching FF Dev tools (CTRL+SHIFT+I from FireFox)? Is there anything in that output that could reveal a clue?